# como configurar https en xampp sin certificado

Tags: apache, xampp, http, https

Tengo múltiples dominios en `http`

```
<VirtualHost ejemplo.com.mx:80> 
<VirtualHost ejemplo2.com.mx:80>
```

y un tercero en `https`

```
<VirtualHost ejemplo3.mx:443>
    ServerAdmin correo@empresa.mx
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ejemplo3.mx"
    ServerName ejemplo3.
     SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/example.crt"   
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/example.key"
    ServerAlias www.example3.mx
    ErrorLog "logs/example3.mx-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/example3.mx-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Hasta este punto no hay ningún problema puedo acceder por `http` a 2 los primeros y `https` al tercero.

El problema es que si el cliente pone `https://ejemplo.com.mx` en su sitio sin que este  tenga certificado lo redirecciona a `https:ejemplo3.mx`

¿Como evito este redireccionamiento?

Comment: Parece haber un error de escritura en el archivo de configuración que presentás, la última dirección debería ser `ejemplo3.com.mx` (falta `.com`) y la directiva ServerName parece estar incompleta (y es la que utiliza apache para redireccionar).

Comment: no solo lo puse asi de ejemplo mi redireccionamiento esta bien, todo funciona bien pero si el cliente le pone https a su web in que esta este habilitada para uso https le muestra la pagina que si tiene https es decir otra web diferente a la suya